# Creating dynamic title tags for each page in an included header.php file.

Tags: php, variables, dynamic

I've looked all over and even watched a simple Youtube video on how to create dynamic titles for each page cause you don't want each page having the same title, right? Right.

So in my header.php file I've created a variable between the head tags like so:

```
<head prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns# fb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb# article: http://ogp.me/ns/article#">
<title><?php echo ['$pagetitle']; ?></title>
```

And of course in one of my index.php files I've defined the variable like so:

```
<?php $pagetitle = 'some-page-title'; ?>
```

It can't get any simpler than this by creating a variable and defining what that variable will be called. But it seems this isn't flying.

I'm using PHP5.6 in XAMPP for testing purposes, and I also use Netbeans which isn't correcting me for the way I created the PHP code; and I'm getting a "undefined variable" page_title and an ARRAY to string conversion in the header.php file. I have defined the variable so why am I getting an array error thrown at me? There must be something I'm missing cause I've looked closely at everything.

Thanks for taking the time to view and answer!

Comment: have you tried `<?php echo $pagetitle; ?>` ?

Comment: @WilliamPerron, yes and I still get a undefined variable: pagetitle on line 4 of the header.php file and netbeans gives me a yellow bulb on that line that says remove surrounding tag. What? There is no surrounding tag.

Comment: are you including `header.php` in your `index.php`?

Comment: @WilliamPerron, I had no idea that If I put the variable statement above the includes and the /n statement killed the array error. 'code' <?php $title = "mytitle"; ?>
<?php require_once("includes/header.php"); ?>
<?php include_once("includes/social.php"); ?>

<?php

Comment: are you sure the file gets included properly? try putting `<? echo "Hello World!" ?> in `header.php`. If it doesn't show, you might want to re-check the include path of the file

Comment: @WilliamPerron, when using XAMPP (not sure if you've used it for testing purposes), the includes path is in xampp/php/pear/ directory which is where I had to create the folder and put my files in there, which is weird. But as long as I have ('includes/path/to/my/ files'), it never complains at me. I'm very happy I got to learn something new again! Thanks for your answer, when there are so many others on here that have asked the same question, but got difficult answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did exactly that for my projects.
index.phtml

```
<html>
    <head>
        <?php
            $title = "Some title";
            require_once("includes/header.php");        
        ?>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- whatever code ... -->
    </body>
</html>
```

includes/header.php

```
<?php
    echo "<title>$title</title>\n";
    # something else if needed...
?>
```

Works just fine.

Comment: Thanks again @Nic;  and how do you mark the 'code' on here? I can't hit the enter key to make another paragraph either. This has got to be the simplest one yet and others that I have read made it seem so scientific and difficult. Like us newbies have been coding for decades! I'm still learning about PHP and I LOVE it!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help   In question and answers, to let the editor know it is code, indent each line with 4 spaces.  Play a bit with it, you will catch on fast.  Notes for comments, you cannot multi-line or code, comments have a very limited format.